# Wordpress Include template in another one

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custome wordpress template and I would like to include in it another template.
Basically I have a review form in which I want to include a field to edit user display name and this field is in another template.

Here is my folder structure:

- child-theme/

  user-display-name-template.php

  - review-template-folder/

    review-template.php

I want to include user-display-name-template.php in review-template.php (that is in the child sub-folder review-template-folder)
What's the best way to obtain this result.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using 'get_template_part'?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

So in your case you would use:

```
get_template_part('user-display-name-template');
```

Comment: Tried but it returns "Sorry, no page was found."

Comment: You wouldn't get that error regarding template includes, that sounds like a potential permalink issue

Comment: I managed to found the issue, it was an if condition in the included template itself. Now it works ok. Thank you.